# Do events in Junkenstein's Revenge happen at specific times?

Tags: overwatch

After playing Junkenstein's Revenge a few times, I've started to notice a pattern in the order of events. Reaper spawns, then Roadhog, then Junkrat, then Reaper again, then Reaper again, then Mercy. Do these events happen at specific marks on the timer? Or do they happen a certain time after the previous boss was defeated? Additionally, are the tire spawns also scripted, or are they random?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**. All spawns are scripted across all difficulty levels, and will happen at the same time every time. Here's a list of the most important spawn times to know, from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/573456/how_to_take_no_damage_to_the_door_on_medium/):

> These times are based on time remaining.
>
> - 5:32 Left tire
> - 4:41 Reaper
> - 3:53 Center tire
> - 3:32 Left tire
> - 3:24 Right tire
> - 2:45 Roadhog
> - 2:21 Right tire
> - 1:45 Junkrat
> - 1:30 Reaper
> - 0:48 Tire x 2: Right+Left
> - 0:33 Center Tire
> - 0:22 Reaper
> - -5 seconds Final battle

Note that spawns will happen regardless of whether or not a previous hero is still alive; it is possible to have both Junkrat and Roadhog on the battlefield at 1:45, for example.

Comment: Can you have 2 reapers out? like say you dont kill the reaper that spawns at 1:30 and the timer counts down to 0:22. would you get two reapers then?

Comment: @Dragonrage No. Reaper just refills his HP.

Comment: @Schism well, where is the fun in that? It would be a lot more amusing having multiple reapers out there.

Comment: You'd probably struggle to stay alive to be honest. Reaper does get death blossom eventually, and all 4 players being dead at the same time is a failure state

Answer (score 6):

Yes, spawn times are scripted, even for the Zomnics. At the very start of the match, you'll notice that Zomnics always spawn in the same locations, in order: middle, left, right.

I don't have the exact times that Reaper, Roadhog, and Junkrat spawn (and I'm at work so I can't test right now) but if you check the score during a match, you'll see a timer counting down at the top of the screen. When this timer reaches zero, the "final battle" will begin and Mercy will spawn. After Mercy spawns, the game ends once you take out all the enemy heroes.

Comment: Do the previous 3 heroes (Reaper, roadhog, Junkrat), respawn in the same location they died in? An employable strategy if they do is to kite Reaper and Roadhog into the side room on the right, then grenade + dragonstrike them while they're in a confined space to burst them down.

Comment: They always revive at fixed locations. At least that's what I observed while playing

Comment: Anecdotally, after playing a few times, it seems that one of Reaper's revivals occurs after Junkenstein takes a certain amount of damage. It doesn't seem to be tied to a timer in that instance.

Answer (score 3):

As Mage said, spawn times are scripted and happen when the timer reaches a certain number.

- Reaper / "The Reaper": **5'**
- Roadhog / "Dr. Junkenstein's Monster": **2'50**
- Junkrat / "Dr. Junkenstein": **1'30**
- Mercy / "The Witch": **0'00**

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/574o1w/junkensteins_revenge_a_guide_to_hard_mode/)

Comment: I feel like this list is incomplete/imprecise. I know Reaper spawns at least 3 times.

Comment: @Unionhawk and as a semi-unrelated note, Reaper seems to be easier to target with Deadeye with each new appearance.

Comment: The linked guide says that Reaper shows up with Mercy, and something about another respawn. The other one might not be timed?

Comment: As suggested by @SirBraneDamuj in a comment on the other answer, one of Reaper's revivals seems to be tied to damage dealt to Junkenstein... so not "timed" per se, but still a fixed sequence.